# Static Library in a Project: Why the frameworks used by the static library needs to be added also to the Project?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, static-libraries, linker-errors

I am developing a static library, which is added to my main project that tests the static library's functions. The static library inside is using some 3rd party components, and this third party components needs to add some additional libraries (e.g.: libz.dylib, SystemConfiguration.Framework). It's fine, but when I try to build my main project that contains my static library, I got bunch of linker errors. I figured out, if I add the same frameworks and libraries to the main projects what I needed to add to my static library, the linker errors disappear and the project is built succesfully. The question is do I really need to add all of those resources to the main Project? I find it crazy that if I give my static library to someone else to use, I need to include a bunch of frameworks and libraries in the documentation that has to be added also in the integrator project? Or am I missing something important?

Answer (score 0):

It's because a static library is not linked, unlike an executable or dynamic library.

A static library is just an archive of object files, and object files contain external references to symbols they use.  Those references are not resolved until the executable/dynamic library is linked.

Therefore when you link-in a static library you are responsible for providing any dependant libraries to the linker, which can themselves be either static or dynamic.